# Fibonacci Recursion using Golden Ratio(Golden Number)

Tags: c, algorithm, fibonacci

i can do a recursive function to compute the nth Fibonacci term as follows:

```
int rec (int i)
{
  if(i == 1 || i == 2)
    return i;
else return rec(i-1)+rec(i-2);
```

}

But i want to use the golden number which is 1.618 to compute the Fibonacci; but my attempt fails, i get wrong numbers:

```
int rec (int i)
{
  if(i == 1 || i ==  2)
    return i;

  else return 1.618*rec(i-1);

 }
```

How can i get it to work?

Comment: you are casting it to `int` implicitly, use `double`

Comment: even though, lets say i call rec(6), i get 13.7 instead of 13

Comment: @ogzd Fibonacci numbers are integer, so it should be ok for the last return. The real problem is that for low numbers you can't use the rule just with integers.

Comment: As answered by Cam below, your programming isn't wrong; your math is. The ratio between numbers in the Fibonacci series asymptotically approaches phi as the numbers get higher, but it's never exactly phi.

Comment: @Noxbru he can always cast back to `int` , though it will still not be the exact fibonacci nums.

Comment: by the way, 1.67 instead of phi works for the first 9 terms, any reasonable explanation for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The golden ratio [is an irrational number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Irrationality), so you shouldn't necessarily expect to be able to plug an approximation of it into a formula to get an exact result.

If you want to know how to calculate the `n`th fibonacci number quickly, here is a page that lists a variety of methods in decreasing order of runtime (but increasing in order of implementation difficulty): https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the [Binet's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Relationship_to_Fibonacci_sequence), do something like this:

```
long fib(int i) {
    double phi = // Golden Ratio
    return Math.round((Math.pow(phi, i) - Math.pow(-phi, -i)) / Math.sqrt(5));
}
```

Note that the above formula is not recursive. I am not aware of any recursive formulas for calculating the fib. sequence using the golden ratio.

Comment: This will not always return a correct result because phi is actually an irrational number, so this function will only approximate fibonacci numbers (likely with increasing accuracy as you add accuracy to your approximation of phi).

Comment: Correct. But how would you use the golden ratio?

Comment: If given `n`, you could calculate a maximum required error bound on an approximation of `phi` required in order to calculate the `n`th fibonacci number using Binet's formula, then you could use a golden ratio approximation algorithm like [this](http://nrich.maths.org/2737) and then plug the result into Binet's. Although I don't know why such an approach would be considered necessary or interesting.

Comment: @Cam I did a little experiment, and found that the results are correct for `n > 44`. I wonder if this is proven mathematically also...

Comment: Do you mean for n < 44? In my experiment (https://gist.github.com/cammckinnon/5021833) I found that it only worked for small enough values - not large enough values.

Comment: I wonder how hard it would be to calculate the number of digits required in phi to calculate the nth fibonacci number. It would be interesting if it was better than linear in `n`, because then it would be cheapear space-wise to precalculate and store the golden ratio and use it to calculate the fibonacci numbers than storing a table of the fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @Cam Since `F(n)` has `Theta(n)` digits, you also need `Theta(n)` digits of phi to correctly compute `F(n)` this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your math appears to be flawed, and you're rounding too often. I used [this formula](http://www.goldennumber.net/fibonacci-series/).

This works:

```
double gr = 1.618033988749895;
int rec (int i)
{
   return (int)round(rec2(i)/(gr+2));
}

double rec2 (int i)
{
  if (i == 1)
    return gr;

  else return gr*rec2(i-1);
}
```

Also, it doesn't really need to be recursive:

```
static int rec (int i)
{
  return (int)round(pow(gr, i)/(gr+2);
}
```

I didn't check too many numbers, but it [appears to be quite accurate (Java)](http://ideone.com/07N8l1).

Comment: again, be careful because since we've approximated the golden ratio here the result will be incorrect.

Comment: @Cam Made it more accurate (obviously still not exact).

Comment: It will still fail eventually - in fact I checked it with a python script and in this case it seems to fail at 71. https://gist.github.com/cammckinnon/5021833 (oops - didn't notice you had added your own test :) )

Comment: @Cam It's only because the provided golden ratio is an estimate, if I add a few hundred digits and use a library that handles massive precision, it takes a while, but computes correctly.

Comment: @Dukeling Eventually, it will produce the wrong result, no matter how many digits you have. Once `F(n) > 1/error`, `F(n+1)` will come out wrong if `F(n)` was still correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do this:

```
double gr = 1.618033988749895;
        double FibGoldenRatio(int i)
        {
            if (i == 1 )
                return 1;

            return  Math.Round(gr * FibGoldenRatio(i - 1));

        }
```

Here Example of output:

```
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181
6765
10946
17711
28657
46368
75025
121393
196418
317811
514229
832040
1346269
2178309
3524578
5702887
9227465
14930352
24157817
39088169
63245986
102334155
165580141
267914296
433494437
701408733
1134903170
1836311903
2971215073
4807526976
7778742049
12586269025
20365011074
32951280099
53316291173
86267571272
139583862445
225851433717
365435296162
591286729879
956722026041
1548008755920
2504730781961
4052739537881
6557470319842
10610209857723
17167680177565
27777890035288
44945570212853
72723460248141
117669030460994
190392490709135
308061521170129
498454011879264
806515533049393
1.30496954492866E+15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the golden ratio yourself and use it to find the nth Fibonacci number.

```
long long fib(int n) {
    double phi = (1 + sqrt(5))/2.0; // golden ratio
    double phi_hat = (1 - sqrt(5))/2.0; // fraction part of golden ratio

    return (pow(phi, n) - pow(phi_hat, n))/sqrt(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this thread is way too old but non have gave correct answer.
I hope below will help some one who is still looking for correct answer.

Golden Ratio is a constant value which is defined as

```
original length / max length == max length / min length
```

In this case

```
fib(n) / fib(n-1) = goldnRation_psi = 1.618033988749895
```

If you are trying to find the nth fibonacci number using golden ratio:

```
(golden ratio) * fib_using_recursive(n-1)
```

**NOTE**: We can use above formula only if we know n-1 the fibanocci value. Above fib_using_recursive() is not a recursive function to goldenratio method.
Incase if n-1 th fibanoci value is not know you may have to calculate using original recursive function or iterative function.

```
    //Golden Ratio
    public static Integer fib_gr(int n){
        double goldnRation_psi = 1.618033988749895;
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(0,0);
        map.put(1,1);
        return (int)Math.round(goldnRation_psi*fib(n-2,map));
    }

    // recursive
    public static int fib(int n,HashMap<Integer,Integer> map){
        // Pick cached value from map instead of repeating calculation for same keys.
        if(map.containsKey(n)){
            return map.get(n);
        }
        else {
            int prevValue = map.containsKey(n-1)?map.get(n-1):fib(n-1,map);
            int nextPrevValue = map.containsKey(n-1)?map.get(n-2):fib(n-2,map);
            map.put(n,prevValue+nextPrevValue);
            return map.get(n);
        }
    }
```